# Como puedo crear un array dinamico en php

Tags: php, sql

estoy trabajando en un sistema donde tengo dos tablas en cuestion.. la primera es `wp_prflxtrflds_user_field_data` que tiene guardada el `departamento, nro de interno y sucursal de un usuario`. 
El problema es que estos tres datos se guardan en un campo llamado `user_value`, y puedo distinguir si es un departamento u otra cosa a traves de un campo llamado `field_id`.
La segunda es el campo wp_users que tiene el nombre y email del usuario.
Por otra parte tengo una tabla donde la deseo mostrar.. entonces me encontre con el problema de que si quiero mostrar el departamento, la sucursal y su nro de interno me trae en 3 registros...
repitiendo el nombre, el email pero me trae obviamente el departamento y sucursal en registros diferentes por que en realidad es asi.

Entonces para mostrar ordenadamente lo hice de esta forma..

```
$sql="SELECT d.user_id, d.field_id, d.user_value,
                            u.ID, u.display_name, u.user_email
                            FROM wp_prflxtrflds_user_field_data as d,
                            wp_users as u
                            WHERE (d.user_id = 675) 
                            and (u.ID = d.user_id) 
                            and (d.field_id = 3 or d.field_id = 1 or d.field_id = 4)";
                        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                        $pila = array();
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                               if (!in_array($row["display_name"], $pila)) {
                                   array_push($pila, $row["display_name"]);
                               }
                               if (!in_array($row["user_email"], $pila)) {
                                   array_push($pila, $row["user_email"]);
                               }
                               if ($row["field_id"] == 3) {
                                   array_push($pila, $row["user_value"]);
                               } else if ($row["field_id"] == 1) {
                                   array_push($pila, $row["user_value"]);
                               } else if ($row["field_id"] == 4) {
                                   array_push($pila, $row["user_value"]);
                               }
                            } 
                        }
                        echo "<td>".$pila[0]."</td>";   
                        echo "<td>".$pila[1]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$pila[2]."</td>";    
                        echo "<td>".$pila[3]."</td>";   
                        echo "<td>".$pila[4]."</td>";
```

Que lo unico que hace es traer los registros del usuario y cargarlos en un array sin que se repitan. pero solo funciona para un usuario en especifico.. ya que si traigo todos los registros me van a cargar todos en el mismo array y ahi ya no tengo idea de como mostrarlos ordenadamente...
Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor explicar mejor tu pregunta ya que no está muy claro el problema?  Gracias.

Comment: tambien podrias incluir el resultado deseado!

Comment: que parte no entienden?

Comment: yo no entiendo si tu error es que no imprimen o que quedan duplicados los registros cuando son más de 1 usuario

Comment: EL codigo anda.. lo que no se es como mostrarlos con muchos registros ya que este solo muestra el de una persona.. y no se como mostrarlo porque en el campo user_value se guardan el departamento, nro de interno y sucursal, y son tres rtegistros diferentes para una persona.